# Fail to call reddit's /api/submit

Tags: node.js, reddit, node-request

I couldn't get any help on reddit/r/redditdev so I'm hoping you fine folks at stackoverflow can help

I'm trying to call [/api/submit](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth#POST_api_submit).

1. I can successfully log the user in and retrieve the bearer/access token. (I use passport-reddit node module for this)
2. I can successfully call /api/needs_captcha
3. When /needs_captcha returns true, I can successfully call /api/new_captcha
4. I can display captcha image to the user
5. Now I try to call submit using nodejs' request module like so

   ```
   var options = {
     url: 'https://oauth.reddit.com/api/submit',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
         'Authorization': 'bearer '+usertoken
       , 'user-agent': 'node.js'
     },
     json: data
   } 
   request(options, function(error, response, body) ...
   ```

A sample of my "data" variable looks like this:

```
{ api_type: 'json',
  kind: 'self',
  sr: 'test',
  title: 'more test',
  text: 'hello world',
  iden: 'o6NsDh4IMCDb2To2DeUXJAgEPkB4O7uS',
  captcha: 'WZRTBL' }
```

But I get this back:

```
{
  "jquery":[
    [0,  1,  "call", ["body"]],
    [1,  2,  "attr", "find"],
    [2,  3,  "call", [".status"]],
    [3,  4,  "attr", "hide"],
    [4,  5,  "call", []],
    [5,  6,  "attr", "html"],
    [6,  7,  "call", [""]],
    [7,  8,  "attr", "end"],
    [8,  9,  "call", []],
    [1,  10, "attr", "captcha"],
    [10, 11, "call", ["1oWOOhcicpcpdwjENw5KrR2xHRl7J0aS"]],
    [1,  12, "attr", "find"],
    [12, 13, "call", [".error.BAD_CAPTCHA.field-captcha"]],
    [13, 14, "attr", "show"],
    [14, 15, "call", []],
    [15, 16, "attr", "text"],
    [16, 17, "call", ["care to try these again?"]],
    [17, 18, "attr", "end"],
    [18, 19, "call", []]
  ]
}
```

Also, I tried running this as a different user, one that has enough karma points and didn't require the captcha.

After I posted, I got this response which seems to indicate success:

```
{
  "jquery":[
    [0, 1, "call", ["body"]],
    [1, 2, "attr", "find"],
    [2, 3, "call", [".status"]],
    [3, 4, "attr", "hide"],
    [4, 5, "call", []],
    [5, 6, "attr", "html"],
    [6, 7, "call", [""]],
    [7, 8, "attr", "end"],
    [8, 9, "call", []]
  ]
}
```

But I can't find my posted message in the /r/test subreddit.

I must be doing something wrong entirely...

Comment: For reference, [here](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_submit) is the documentation for that endpoint.

Comment: Does it look any different if you set `extension` to "json"?

Comment: Also, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/3d36jl/getting_errorbad_captchafieldcaptcha_on_apisubmit/) is the /r/redditdev thread.

Comment: I'm using that doc reference but I wish it was more descriptive, perhaps with examples. I posted this question on /r/redditdev already a few days ago and couldn't get any answers. I haven't tried extension: "json" but I can. Why do you think that'll help?

Comment: @kane http://www.reddit.com/r/rawjs/wiki/documentation

Comment: @stdob thanks. if all else fails, I'll try this. I really would like to understand what I'm doing wrong though since this is more of a learning exercise than a project that needs to get done

Comment: What about posting to `https://oauth.reddit.com/api/submit.json`?

Answer (score 6):

After going through different documentation related to /api/submit, I have discovered that you have missed the field `uh` of your sample of "data". Missing of `uh` entails to errors that look like yours (look documentation below)

Here more documentation related what I said:

https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API:-submit
http://www.reddit.com/dev/api

Comment: The doc also says that "uh" is not required when logging in with OAuth, which I am doing. Also, my error message does not contain "please login to do that" so it's not the same error

Comment: I will try to find more information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your User-Agent header to something more descriptive. See the guidelines here: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API. I've heard of people having issues just using a generic user agent string like `node.js`.

If you are still having trouble, the Apigee console (https://apigee.com/console/reddit) has helped me debug issues with the reddit API. Just add your User-Agent header and the Authorization token and mess with different parameters through the console, if that's faster than building changes to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem, and the fix (to the your second error) was to not send as JSON but as a query in the URI.

```
/api/submit?api_type=json&kind=self&sr=test&title=more%20test&text=hello%20world
```

Append any other fields as needed.

Keep the 'url', 'method', and 'headers' that you used.

That should then return a json like so:

```
"json": {
    "data": {
        "id": "12abcd",
        "name": "t3_12abcd",
        "url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/test/comments/12abcd/more_test/"
    },
    "errors": []
}
```